# Mongodb Server Whitelist

Tags: mongodb, whitelist, mongodb-security

Performed the following steps as per the Mongodb Document : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/security/
1. User authentication
2. TLS/SSL implementation

My question is can we implement IPWhiteList for Mongodb Server?
If not, then is there any other security setup which can help us to secure our Mongodb database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe `security.clusterIpSourceWhitelist` is what you need. More details [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.clusterIpSourceWhitelist)